# Midi volume control

Tags: midi

I am building a footswitch board for a software looper , and need to be able to change the volume on each of four channels . I can do it in a roundabout way by controlling the cursor on the GUI with macros , but it would be simpler via midi. I have a midi continuous controller that I can use via cc#7 but it will not work because if I switch from one channel that is on volume 127 to one that is 108 the controller needs to start controlling at the appropriate level , not impose it's existing setting (the position of a variable resistor). So instead of the continuous controller what is needed is an instruction in midi that just says "volume down" if I press one button, and "volume up" if I press another. 
Any pointers to where I could go with this greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest the mothership -  https://stackoverflow.com itself. It's really a coding question, not one that musicians are going to be able to answer.

Comment: I agree with Tetsujin's suggestion.  I have a USB foot pedal which I use to turn pages in a PDF using software I wrote.  I can easily imaging taking the software library for the foot pedal (I used HIDSharp) and bolting it on to a software library for MIDI control and there's your volume control.

Comment: Some software will set the new value and will not alter it until input from a control. If it waits for actual input, then perhaps adding 2 springs to the expression pedal that return it to a neutral position (calibrated to mid-swing) when one's foot is lifted would give you what you want. I imagine madly trying to multi-tap a footswitch for more volume would be distracting

Comment: Thanks for replies. At the moment I'm exploring using a python script via pyautogui.

Comment: The problem with a midi pedal is that when channel is switched the pedal will talk to the software and set the new channel at whatever volume the pedal is sitting at. The pedal needs to say "ignore me until I move and then start from where volume is now ( a number 0-127 in Midi) and move (up or down)" The mid-position would work but the volume would drop or rise until you'd moved it back to the right place I think. But if python doesn't work I'll try it and see how it goes.